# how to design agg funtion for pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

my dataFrame is like this:

```
user,rating, f1,f2,f3,f4

20, 3, 0.1, 0, 3, 5

20, 4, 0.2, 3, 5, 2

18, 4, 0.6, 8, 7, 2

18, 1, 0.7, 9, 2, 7
```

I want to compute a profile for a user, for instance

for user 20, it should be `3*[0.1,0,3,5]+4*[0.2,3,5,2]`
which is a weighted sum of `f1` to `f4`

How should I write a `agg` function to complete this task?

```
df.groupby('user').agg(....)
```

Comment: what do you mean by weighted sum? by `3*[0.1,0,3,5]` do you actually mean `3*(0.1+0+3+5)`?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x : sum(x['rating'] * (x['f1']+x['f2']+x['f3']+x['f4'])))
```

Comment: what if  I don't know the column name for f1,f2,f3,f4, and there are 200 such columns? (for example, those column names are long urls, which is impossible to cite them explicitly), and those columns are those except for ['user','rating']